# How to unlock/lock search button on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am working on one specific field in form. When I enter the text that has less than 3 letters then should disable the search button on keyboard. When it has 3 or more it should enable it. I tried by accessing UISearchBar property but it doesnt work.

This is what I wrote:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    
    let textFieldInsideSearchBar = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    
    if itsBicApiCallEnabled && searchText.count >= 3 {
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = true
    } else {
        textFieldInsideSearchBar?.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
    }
}
```

I tried by accessing UISearchBar property but it doesnt work.

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey` instead of the `searchTextField` property?

Comment: Because I was thinking searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") is taking the search button on keyboard and saving it into a variable to manipulate it.

Comment: `searchTextField` is the text field in the search bar